# PHP implode function in if and foreach condition

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, implode

This is my HTML Code

```
<input type="checkbox" value="fotoğraf" name="materyal[]"> Fotoğraf
<input type="checkbox" value="resim" name="materyal[]">Resim
<input type="checkbox" value="çizelge" name="materyal[]">Çizelge
<input type="checkbox" value="katlanabilir harita" name="materyal[]"> Katlanabilir Harita
```

There are checkbox and i'll take values with $_POST['materyal'] and then i want to write screen values with comma if values more than one. if checkbox values empty i don't write anything screen.

```
if (isset($_POST['materyal']) && !empty($_POST['materyal'])) {
        $materyal = $_POST['materyal'];
        echo "İçerdiği extra materyaller ; ";

        foreach ($materyal as $materyallist) {
            foreach ($materyallist as $yenimateryal){
                array_push($sonmateryal, $yenimateryal);
            }
        }
        echo implode(", ", $sonmateryal);
    }
```

This is my code. when i want to use implode in if contiditon, I take mistake.
How can i do

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: If you want to see an array content, you should use print_r(implode(", ", $yenimateryal)); Edit: Nevertheless, in your case, the variable $yenimateryal is not in the scope, so that's probably the error

Comment: @Leonardo that dosent make any sense implode returns a string and you shouldnt use print_r on strings echo like here is perfectly acceptable

Comment: You don't need to check `isset` - `empty` already does that check and does not issue a warning if the variable is not set.  [see php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just want to show the contents?

```
$sonmateryal = array();
if (isset($_POST['materyal']) && !empty($_POST['materyal'])) {
    echo "İçerdiği extra materyaller ; ";
    foreach ($_POST['materyal'] as $materyallist) {
        foreach ($materyallist as $yenimateryal) {
            $sonmateryal[] = $yenimateryal;
        }
    }
}
echo implode(", ", $sonmateryal);
```

**update according to given HTML**

```
if (!empty($_POST['materyal'])) {
    echo "İçerdiği extra materyaller ; ".htmlentities(implode(',', $_POST['materyal']));
}
```

Since you're posting the inputs as simple array's this will implode the results with a comma if the post-ed value isn't empty..

Comment: Thanks so much Gekkie, but i take mistake 5. row in here foreach ($materyallist as $yenimateryal) and dont comes selected values screen.

Comment: Hmmm... i see you've posted the html... i've updated my answer